How do I remove the attribution on the TWebLeafletMaps component in TMS WEB Core?
When I put a TWebLeafletMaps component on my form, then there's a small "Leaflet" attribution line at the bottom right of my map like this:

Normally in JavaScript when you initialize the leaflet map, then one of the options you can set is the attributionControl property. You simply set this property to false and then the attribution won't display like in this JavaScript code:
var map = L.map('map', {attributionControl: false}).setView([0, 0]);

But I can't do this in Delphi, because I'm not the one initializing the map. I simply place the component onto the form and then it gets created and set automatically. I also don't see a design-time property for this on the component.
So how can I disable or remove the attribution line on the TWebLeafletMaps component?
I also don't want it disabled for all leaflet maps on my website. So a global setting or something isn't what I need. I need to only disable the attribution line for a specific map.

I'm still hoping there's a hidden property or function I can simply call and use on the TWebLeafletMaps component to disable the attribution like there is with JavaScript, but in the meantime, I've found a solution.
The TWebLeafletMaps component renders a <div> with the class leaflet-control-attribution that is used for the attribution. So I wrote the following Delphi programming procedure that can be used to enable and disable the attribution:
procedure LeafletMapsAttribution(Map: TWebLeafletMaps; Enabled: Boolean);
var
  Attribution: TJSHTMLElement;
  DisplayStyle: String;
begin
  Attribution := TJSHTMLElement(Map.ElementHandle.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-control-attribution')[0]);
  if Enabled then DisplayStyle := 'block' else DisplayStyle := 'none';
  Attribution.style.setProperty('display', DisplayStyle);
end;

It'll still be there, but at least the user won't see it.
To use this function, you simply pass your component as the first param and the Enabled status on the second param.
So to hide the attribution do LeafletMapsAttribution(Map, False) and to show the attribution do LeafletMapsAttribution(Map, True).

Vladimir Agafonkin, the creator of Leaflet, says it's okay to remove his attribution: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/leaflet-js/fA6M7fbchOs/JTNVhqdc7JcJ

That's clearly a copyright infringement of OpenStreetMap - if you don't want to show such a notice you're not free to use any of their data.

@AmigoJack It's not specific to the OpenStreetMap part. It's for the whole attribution line. The Attribution option is for the whole attribution section. You can use many other things in Leaflet. Not just OpenStreetMap.

Your question doesn't indicate this and is only concerned about OpenStreetMap - it's not consistent to now say otherwise.

@AmigoJack People who use Leaflet know this. No need to indicate it. The question is about how to remove the attribution line. It doesn't matter what's in the attribution as it's not about anything specific in the attribution because removing it is the same regardless of what's in it.

Don't let me state again that this is one of your dozens of answers that simply use basic CSS knowledge. "People who use" CSS "know this. No need to indicate it." Of course the HTML element's content doesn't matter, yet removing a copyright notice is almost always an infringement, unbound to OpenStreetMap. You're just using free data and don't even want to signal users where it comes from - then nobody knows the original source and the latter quietly dies the more people don't know/reference it. You'll learn what this means if people do it on your work (but then it's too late).

It would help if you could indicate WHY you want to remove the whole attribution, Leaflet as well as the the map tile service's, as that's what's going to happen if the standard Leaflet control is hidden. TMS's blog notes "Usually it is required to attribute the service used. The attribution text is specified in the details for each service."  Had your question's image not circled the OpenStreetMap service's attribution, which as @AmigoJack indicates is clearly an infringement of their license, I could maybe see a valid reason for this.

@jwd630 The attribution is only required for OpenStreetMaps and it doesn't even have to be on the actual map component. You just have to give attribution somewhere. Also, I'm not using OpenStreetMaps anyway. I remove OpenStreetMaps, I'm just using the leaflet part and it's completely okay to remove the leaflet attribution. But also, whether it's allowed or not allowed to remove it is not relevant to this question at all because I didn't ask if it's allowed or not. I just asked how to do it regardless of whether it's allowed or not.
